# Gulp: How to run multiple instances of gulp?

Tags: gulp

It used to work, if I run gulp with one or few instances already running, it will find new port (3001, 3002, 3003, 3004, [...]) and run without any issue.

I tweaked code occasionally and then I noticed that it doesn't work anymore. I don't know when it stopped working and what changed. It demands to run on only port 3000, without automatically finding new port and running on it.

Can anyone look at my gulpfile.js to see anything that is stopping from multiple instances running?

**Error:**

```
λ gulp
[19:32:57] Using gulpfile D:\Dev\Projects\NASDAQ\gulp\gulpfile.js
[19:32:57] Starting 'sass'...
[19:32:57] Finished 'sass' after 29 ms
[19:32:57] Starting 'serve'...
[19:33:07] Finished 'serve' after 10 s
[19:33:07] Starting 'default'...
[19:33:07] Finished 'default' after 5.43 μs
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:837:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:860:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1231:14)
    at listen (net.js:1267:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1363:5)
    at module.exports.plugin (D:\Dev\Projects\NASDAQ\gulp\node_modules\browser-sync\lib\server\index.js:24:25)
    at Object.module.exports.startServer [as fn] (D:\Dev\Projects\NASDAQ\gulp\node_modules\browser-sync\lib\async.js:236:52)
    at D:\Dev\Projects\NASDAQ\gulp\node_modules\browser-sync\lib\browser-sync.js:149:14
    at iterate (D:\Dev\Projects\NASDAQ\gulp\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\async-each-series\index.js:8:5)
    at D:\Dev\Projects\NASDAQ\gulp\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\async-each-series\index.js:16:16
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

// Static Server + watching scss/html files
gulp.task('serve', ['sass'], function() {

    browserSync.init({
        server: "..",
        notify: false
    });

    gulp.watch("../assets/scss/*.scss", ['sass']);
    gulp.watch("../**/*").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

// Compile sass into CSS & auto-inject into browsers
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src("../assets/scss/*.scss")
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sass.sync().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("../assets/css"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

I hope this issue can be resolved. Thanks.

Comment: Try specifying a different port?

Comment: @aug Thank you for a response. As indicated on my original post, gulp used to automatically find and open new port (3002, 3003, 3004, [...]) if default port is in use, therefore gulp is capable of such thing. Perhaps it's BrowserSync rather than gulp, but I'm unable to debug to find out which tasks are responsible for this. I would like gulp to automatically find and open new port instead of manually entering a different port whenever I'm current running an instance.